# SIM/Javacard - Can't send INS 69 or 96

Tags: smartcard, sim-card

I got bored and tried all the INS codes to my SIM through PCSC reader.

I got a weird behavior - when I uses the CLA 80 and the INS 69 or 96 I get an exception in my program.

I know that INS 6X and 9X are invalid, but only for those 2 values (69 and 96) I get an exception every time.

Can someone explain me why?

Thanks for the helpers :)

BTW - I tried it using the smartcard.scard (python), SCARD (c++) and smartcardio (Java).

Comment: This is probably because of `T=0` protocol, where these bytes are used, see ISO 7816-3...

Comment: @vlp like I mentioned I know that 6x & 9x are invalid. But only for those 2 i get an execption.

Comment: (Assuming you get some meaningful status word for the other INS values -- which you didn't write): If I remember well, it is because there is a moment during the T=0 protocol when card echoes the INS/~INS or responds with a 6XXX/9XXX status word. As these two can't be distinguished the 6X/9X INS are forbidden. The same situation should be the INS of '60' where this value is used for time extension. (I would write an answer, but I am quite busy to study ISO 7816-3 now...I am sorry)

Comment: AFAIK It is the green PB byte on [this picture](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/whatissmartcardontam-161228073954/95/what-is-smart-card-on-tam-14-638.jpg)

Comment: @vlp for the 60 and all the other I get a response (i don't remember right which one). Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I posted some semi-answer, but just to feed my curiosity -- what status word do you get for `INS` of `6X`/`9X`? And are you sure you connect using the `T=0` protocol (I suppose modern (U)SIM cards support `T=1` as well)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why CLA values of `6X` and `9X` are invalid is the way the `T=0` protocol works.

Excerpts from ISO 7816-3:

1. Command header:

> The interface device initiates every command by transmitting a five-byte header that tells the card what to do.
>
> ... skipped ...
>
> The header consists of five bytes denoted CLA, INS, P1, P2 and P3. The
>   values of CLA, INS, P1 and P2 shall  be as specified in ISO/IEC
>   7816-4.
>
> - CLA denotes a class of commands. The value 'FF' is invalid
>     (reserved for PPSS, see 6.3.1 and 9.2).
>
>   NOTE:  ISO/IEC 7816-4 enforces
>     'FF' as invalid value of CLA.
> - **INS denotes an instruction code. The
>     values '6X' and '9X' are invalid.**
>
>   **NOTE:  ISO/IEC 7816-4 enforces '6X'
>     and '9X' as invalid values of INS.**
> - P1 P2 denotes an instruction
>     parameter, e.g., a reference completing the instruction code.
> - P3
>     encodes the number of data bytes denoted D1 to Dn to be transferred
>     during the command.
>
>   - In an outgoing data transfer command, P3='00'
>       introduces a 256-byte data transfer from the card.
>   - In an incoming
>       data transfer command, P3='00' introduces no data transfer.

2. Procedure byte:

> After transmitting the header as a string of five characters, the interface device shall wait for a character 
>   conveying a procedure byte. There are three types of procedure bytes, see Table 11.
>
> - If the
>     value is '60', it is a NULL byte. It requests no action on data
>     transfer. The interface device shall wait  for a character conveying a
>     procedure byte.
> - If the value is '6X' or '9X', except for '60', it
>     is a SW1 byte. It requests no action on data transfer. The  interface
>     device shall wait for a character conveying a SW2 byte. There is no
>     restriction on SW2 value.
>
>   NOTE: ISO/IEC 7816-4 enforces '60' as
>     invalid value of SW1, as well as any value different from '9X' and
>     '6X'.
> - **If the value is the value of INS, apart from the values '6X'
>     and '9X', it is an ACK byte. All remaining data  bytes if any bytes
>     remain, denoted Di  to Dn , shall be transferred subsequently. Then
>     the interface device  shall wait for a character conveying a procedure
>     byte.**
> - **If the value is the exclusive-or of 'FF' with the value of
>     INS, apart from the values '6X' and '9X', it is an  ACK byte. Only the
>     next data byte if it exists, denoted Di , shall be transferred. Then
>     the interface device  shall wait for a character conveying a procedure
>     byte.**
> - Any other value is invalid.
>
> At each procedure byte, the card can proceed with the command by NULL or ACK, or finish the command by 
>   SW1 SW2, or show its disapproval by becoming unresponsive (WT will be exceeded).

3. Status byte:

> The status bytes SW1 SW2 indicate the card status at the end of the command. Their values shall be as 
>   specified in ISO/IEC 7816-4.

---

In other words -- the `INS` values of `9X` and `6X` are forbidden as their ACK byte (either direct or complementary/exclusive-or variant) can't be distinguished from `SW1` at the procedure byte.

---

I admit that this does not explain why you are getting exception only for particular INS values of `69`/`96` and not for the other `6X`/`9X` ones. It is undefined behavior.

Hope this post is useful for you...good luck!